# How to call an async method, and update the UI from there?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, task-parallel-library, async-await

Recently I've finished designing a PagedDataGridView custom control, it works very well, but now I'd like to improve its performance.

How?, well, I've seen some UI blocking when showing new pages.
In short words, this:

```
public class PagedDataGridView() : UserControl
{
    Paging paging = new Paging();

    public PagedDataGridView()
    {
        paging.LoadDataClientMethod = LoadDataOnGrid;
    }

    private void LoadDataOnGrid()
    {
        // Some heavy set data source here, using functions from 'paging' object
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do (using the async / await pattern):
That async method DoPaging pauses until the await 'LoadDataOnGrid' is complete, that way the UI thread is not blocked, be asynchronous.

```
// Class that handles paging methods, variables,
// also offers navigation controls, such as buttons, labels, etc.
internal class Paging
{
    // Represents the method that code client uses to load its own data
    public Action LoadDataClientMethod;

    // HERE: 
    private async Task DoPaging()
    {
        // some calculations

        if (LoadDataClientMethod != null)
        {
            // I realizad that calling Run method, runs it out of context
            // How to run this method, and update the UI
            await Task.Run(() => LoadDataClientMethod());
        }

        // Update controls, showing current page, etc
        UpdateUI();
    }

    // Navigation buttons
    private void btnGoNextPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // go next page calculations

        // Then how to call the async method
        DoPaging(); // -> doing this, VS shows a warning:
        /* Because this call is not awaited, the current method
           continues to run before the call is completed */
    }
}
```

I'm just starting to learn about async - await coding, any correction or advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `I'd like to improve its performance.` - you might want to see [this short clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA). basically, you're running against the wind by using archaic technology and expecting it to deliver world-class features and performance.

Comment: Well, this project is already running and working, it's a little too late to change it. I'm having some free time next week, so I will start a new version with WPF, after seeing this video I'm very excited about it, Thanks.

Comment: *"after seeing this video I'm very excited about it"* - that video is really not a big deal. [this](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) is something to be excited about.

Comment: Is your `LoadDataToGrid` method doing IO bound work (getting stuff from disk/network) or CPU bound (calculation and such)?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov gets data from a BLL interface (database application)

Comment: That is IO bound work. Do you use an ORM (Like Entity Framework) or ADO.NET which provide an async API?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - is it really necessary to add the [.net] tag to all these C# questions?  C# is part of .NET, it's kind of implied.  Besides, you're absolutely flooding the Active tab with edits, and you keep pushing other edits off of the main page as a result.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables These questions get broader views as .NET is a more general tab. But you're right, i'll tone it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between:

```
private void btnGoNextPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoPaging();
}
```

and

```
private async void btnGoNextPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoPaging();
}
```

**Exception handling**. If the former throws an exception, two things might happen:

1. If you're using .NET 4.0, the swallowed task will be re-thrown from the `Finalizer` thread and will cause your application to **crash**
2. If you're using .NET 4.5, the task will be swallowed and will go un-noticed and **will not** be re-thrown at all, thus possibly entering your application in a corrupted state which you wont be aware of.

in the latter example, the exception will propogate to the `await` point, and you can handle it gracefully by adding a `try-catch` block.

As a side note, i asked you in the comments what kind of work is being done that is blocking your UI thread, and you said that you are making a call to your database to retrieve data.
Work being done against a database is IO bound work, and most providers expose async endpoints to access data, such as Entity Framework, ADO.NET, etc. You can make use of that naturally async behavior by not using any threadpool threads to do the work for you (with `Task.Run` as you're doing in your example). You can do that when you go *"async all the way"*, and your database query can be used with the `await` keyword. That way, while the query is retrieving the data, the thread that invoked the query (in your example, the UI thread) is freed and can do more work, thus your UI will stay responsive.

I suggest you look into that and see if your database provider has those async endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, about the work done on `LoadDataOnGrid` method, the actual retrieved data belongs to a `IEnumerable<T>` collection sent by an BLL interface (n-layer application), this collection takes some processing and data formatting inside the `PagedDataGridView` class, there is no real direct work with the database.

Comment: Is that processing that blocks the UI, it is not critical but could be annoying and I'm sure avoidable doing asynchronous work; after some testing the **worst** response could take between 3000-4000ms, that's why the paging.

Comment: So the work is mainly CPU bound, thats ok. Using `Task.Run` should work fine, but just be careful about the first part of my post, regarding exceptions

Comment: Well, my problem now is that he UI doesn't update when doing `Task.Run`

Comment: When calling `DoPaging`? Are you `Task.Run` is throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes, `TaskRun`, is throwing a `System.InvalidOperationException`, when trying to update the `PagedDataGridView` control.

Comment: `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Comment: If tou want to change UI elements from a background thread, you'll have to use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `async` to the button click event handler method and await the call to `DoPaging()`:

```
private async void btnGoNextPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoPaging();
}
```

The difference between doing it like this rather than the way you had that gives the [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx) (and is in fact why the warning is given) is that if you added any code after the call to `DoPaging()` in the event handler it would now occur after the task has complete, whereas before it would execute immediately after the call.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent in effect to just not awaiting as the op has in his code (meaning both are correct and equivalent as the event handler won't block the UI)?

Comment: @mclaassen oh I see, with that `await` all after DoPaging() will have to _wait_.